# how to define timezone in logstash timestamp

Tags: logstash

Below is my code, I'm parsing event_date to timestamp.

```
date {
    match => [ "event_date" ,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    target => "@timestamp"
}
```

I have also tried below code

```
date {
    match => [ "event_date" ,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    timezone => "Europe/Istanbul"
    target => "@timestamp"
}
```

But none of them worked fine.

event_date is

> 2018-10-20 12:23:46

but timestamp returns

> 2018-10-20T09:23:46.000Z

The difference is about timezone. Turkey timezone is

> GMT+03:00

How can i set it ?
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to change timezone as Istanbul but not working fine. Instead of giving Timezone area we can also define time difference like below

> timezone => "-0000"

That solved my question.